# Как сохранить fragment и его View? При перелистывании он удаляется

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Имеется ViewPager с четырьмя Fragments.

В fragment1 меняю значения для нескольких TextView, но при перелистывании на fragment3 они удаляются.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сохранить эти значения? Или как держать в памяти 4 фрагмента?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решилось с помощью метода setOffscreenPageLimit(int):
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

По умолчанию ViewPager хранит 1 страницу (как я понял, слева и справа от активной), а нужно было в данном методе указать число страниц которые собираетесь хранить.

Answer (score 1):

У вас должен быть реализован PagerAdapter, у которого есть метод

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    ...
}
```

В этом методе у вас сейчас создаётся новый фрагмент каждый раз, у нужно сделать так, чтобы фрагмент созданный сохранялся. Например:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    // other methods

    private FirstFragment firstFragment;

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 1:
                return getFirstFragment();
            case 2:
                ...
        }
    }

    private FirstFragment getFirstFragment() {
       if (firstFragment == null) {
           firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
       }
       return firstFragment;
    }
}
```

Comment: v.andrikeev, я решил проблему с помощью viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3); который увеличивает число хранящихся фрагментов.

Вы были правы что в методе "getItem(int position)" у меня  возвращается "new Fragment1()", однако при перелистывании фрагмент и его значения теперь сохраняются, а следовательно он уже не пересоздается

Comment: Отлично, главное не забыть поменять на viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4), когда/если добавится ещё один Фрагмент ;)